# build rabbitmq-c for iOS (armv6, armv7)

Tags: ios, cmake, rabbitmq

I am having some trouble building [rabbitmq-c](https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c.git) for armv6/armv7.  I am specifying the architecture as such.  It builds fine for i386 but chokes on armv.  Looks like it has a problem looking for a suitable socket lib.  I also get the same result when using the [ios-cmake](https://code.google.com/p/ios-cmake/) toolchain.

```
mkdir build && cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES="i386;armv6;armv7" ..
cmake --build .
```

Anyone out there successful in getting this to build for iOS?  Any hints or recommendations?  I am not a cmake expert (not even close) and have been scratching my head on this for a few days now.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? What library does rabbitmq-c require? If you use "file lib.a" on a library file that has multiple architectures in it, the output will tell you what architectures those are. (If there's only one, it may just say "current ar") - Perhaps the library you need to link to simply does not have an armv6 architecture available.